# angularjs factory wrapper around lodash not loaded in test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, angularjs, karma-runner

So I have the following:

```
angular.module('common.lodash', []).factory('_', function() {
  _.additionFunctionOnLodashThatICreated = function(foo, bar, baz) { ... };
  return _;
});
```

I depend upon lodash in another module:

```
angular.module('common.gridhelper', ['common.lodash']).factory('gridhelper', function(_) {
  var service;
  service.foo = function (collection) {
    // find is a native function on lodash
    return _.find(...);
  }
  return service;
});
```

When I navigate to the site in the browser, everything just "works". However when I try to write a couple tests, I'm getting mixed results.

The following works, so I know my service is accessible:

```
describe('Lodash Service:', function() {
  beforeEach(module('common.lodash'));
  it('should get an instance of the lodash factory', inject(function(_) {
    expect(_).toBeDefined();
  })); 
});
```

However this fails:

```
describe('GridHelper Service:', function() {
  var gh;
  beforeEach(function () {
    angular.module('test', [
      'common.lodash',
      'common.gridhelper'
    ]);
  });
  beforeEach(module('test'));

  it('should return a good foo', inject(function(gridhelper) {
    gridhelper.foo({'a': { 'b': 0 }});
  });
```

Which returns the error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '_.find(...)')
```

For fun, I try to print out '_' in the gridhelper service and it's shown as being null when run via a test, but is populated when run via a browser.

Anyone have thoughts on what piece I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my tests exposed an issue in my implementation. _.find was returning null and I was trying to extract something off that return value without checking first.